# How to convert str to list in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

My input is

[image]

In pandas dataframe I used literal_eval to convert 'hashtags' column from str to list, but I don't know how to do that in Spark Dataframe. Any solution for my case?

Tks all supports for my case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1.withColumn("list_hashtags", expr("from_json(hashtags, 'array<string>')"))
```

Therefore, `list_hashtags[0]` will give you `#ucl`.

Hope this is what you want!

Comment: This worked for my case. Many tks vilalabinot!